# How to create generic interface methods?

Tags: java, generics, interface, delegation

is it possible to create a generic method in interfaces?

say I want to create an interface

```
public interface Merge {
    public void merge(Object host, Object other);
}
```

then I want the implementing class to implement this, but define the type of host and other.

e.g.

```
public class FooBazMerge implements Merge {
    public void merge(Foo host, Baz other){
        // merge some properties
    }
}
```

the reason why I want to do this is so that I can do something like this

```
public class SomeObject {
    private Merge merge;
    private Foo foo;
    private Baz baz;        

    public setMerge(Merge merge){
        this.merge = merge
    }

    public void merge(SomeObject anotherObject){
        merge.merge(this.foo, anotherObject.getBaz()); 
    }
}
```

I basically want to delegate the merging responsibility/logic of someObject to FooBazMerge. that way I can change the implementation of how it's merged without having to muck with the domain models every time an adjustment needs to be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface Merge<A,B> {
    public void merge(A host, B other);
}
```

is this what you are looking for? This is valid syntax. Your implementing class would look like:

```
public class FooBazMerge implements Merge<Foo, Baz> {
    public void merge(Foo host, Baz other){
        // merge some properties
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh! you guys are awesome!. that's what i did wrong. when i did public class FooBazMerge implements Merge<Foo, Baz>, did public class FooBazMerge<Foo, Baz> implements Merge<Foo, Baz>..now that i look back i don't know what in the world i was thinking. thanks aishwarya!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want something like...

```
public interface Merge<T,S> {
    public void merge(T host, S other);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page for nice examples of generic interface implementation.
This should help of how to implement one.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Agenericinterfaceexample.htm